# iFrame javascript affecting parent DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I am injecting inline javascript into a pre-existing frame. This javascript is not affecting the frame it's in at all, rather than parent DOM containing the frame.

I have a JSFiddle demonstrating my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/vfspadgt/

**HTML**

```
<iframe class="editor" id="preview" name="result" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin" frameborder="0">
#document
<!-- Editor content goes here -->
</iframe>

<div class=".dropdown">
    <p>hi2</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var preview = $("#preview").contents();

var css = "<style type='text/css'></style>";

var html = "<p>hi1</p>";
preview.find("head").html(css);

var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.text  = "$('p').remove();";
preview.find("head").append(script);

preview.find("body").html(html);
```

**Results**

**hi1** is within the iFrame and **hi2** is within the parent DOM. The javascript injected into the iFrame however removes **hi2** which it should not have access to, nor should it have access to the jQuery it's using to delete it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to get the `contentDocument` of the iFrame, and create the element in that scope, not with the `document` from the parent window.

Comment: I changed document.createElement("script"); to window.frames[0].document.createElement("script"); but it didn't make a difference. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this myself. The problem was that appending the script to be within the iFrame wasn't enough to make it work. To make the script only be executed within the iFrames DOM was to write directly to it.

I was also creating the script element with the parent document thus giving them a relationship.

```
$("#btnRun").click(function(event) {  
    event.preventDefault();

    var previewDoc = window.frames[0].document;

    var css    = ace.edit("css-editor").getSession().getValue();
    var script = ace.edit("js-editor").getSession().getValue();
    var html   = ace.edit("html-editor").getSession().getValue();

    previewDoc.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    previewDoc.write("<html>");
    previewDoc.write("<head>");
    previewDoc.write("<style type='text/css'>" + css + "</style>");
    previewDoc.write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.onload = function() {" + script + "}</script>");
    previewDoc.write("</head>");
    previewDoc.write("<body>");
    previewDoc.write(html);
    previewDoc.write("</body>");
    previewDoc.write("</html>");
    previewDoc.close();
});
```